# Does a number have a primitive root if and only if φ(n)=λ(n)?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, primitive-roots

From the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) on root primitives:

> In particular, for a to be a primitive root modulo n, φ(n) has to be the smallest power of a which is congruent to 1 modulo n.

Am I correct if I say a number has a primitive root if and only if $φ(n)=λ(n)$ (that is, Euler's Totient Function and Carmichael's Function)?

Answer (score 0):

If the exponent of a finite abelian group equals the order of the group, then the group must be cyclic.  The other direction is a matter of checking that $\varphi(n)=\lambda(n)$ for $n = 2,4,p^k,2p^k$ which is true.